# Wordpress Stripping links and text formatting on Blog Front Page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The summary page of blog posts (Blog Front Page) is not showing the right formatting of copy as per the full blog post.

For example, look at "Article in the Vancouver Sun..." in second article here: http://socialinnovationbc.ca/news/
and then see it in the full post here: http://socialinnovationbc.ca/2011/11/collaboration-innovation-key-to-social-ills/
It has removed the link, plus the  formatting.

Any ideas how to stop it doing that?

Never seen this issue in Wordpress before.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress by default strips html and short-codes while the excerpt is shown. One work around is to add the html in the excerpt text area field for the post. Any html added to the excerpt metabox would not be filtered.

Comment: Thanks so much - also had to change the theme to show the excerpt instead of the content. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt Thanks!